# JQueryUI Drag n Drop not able to Sort after Editable Element is Enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, froala

Hi I'm hoping someone can help me figure out a bug I'm having with a drag n drop sortable.  Currently I have elements on the left side contained within in a div which I call the draggable area.  On the right side I have the drop zone.  The dragging and dropping work just fine with sortable but when I enable an editable function the sorting does not work but the editiable works just fine.

To make the editable work within the drop area I had to add..

```
handle: '.sortable-handle'  to  .sortable({})
```

But when this handle is enabled the sorting stops. I'd like to be able to drag/drop, sort and edit the element within the drop area. Im using Froala text editor for the editable functionality

> Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/darinnj/bdaerfyq/

Let me know if anyone has an effecient way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Actually in your fiddle both the editor and the dragged-sortable functionality will work if you remove the `handle: ".i-match-nothing"`. It's just that making an element draggable makes it more difficult to select text, in order to open the editor. Try double-clicking on a word.

Comment: I started without the "handle:.sortable-handle" and couldn't get the editable text to work in the drop area. When I implement the handle the editable text works but the sortable/draggable is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your jsFiddle with handlers to drag the items after you drop them. http://jsfiddle.net/bdaerfyq/4/

```
$('.contentTitle:not([data-initialized])').editable({
  initOnClick: true,
  buttons: ['formatBlock', 'blockStyle', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'color', 'align', 'outdent', 'indent', 'createLink', 'undo', 'redo', 'inserthorizontalrule'],
  blockTags: ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
}).attr('data-initialized', true).parent().append('<span class="sortable-handle"></span>');
```

Also, it's important to stop propagation on the handler so that it doesn't propagate further to the editor.

```
$('body').on('.sortable-handle', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```